# Sql mapping with column name and first row values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table:

```
C1   C2   C3   C4
--   --   --   --
v11  v12  v13  v14
v21  v22  v23  v24
```

I want the output to be ColumnName and First Row mapped, like below:

```
        NC1   NC2
        --    --  
        C1    v11 
        C2    v12 
        C3    v13
        C4    v14
```

What will be the SQL query for this?

I need to do it dynamically - without knowing actually how much columns I have in the table!

Comment: What about the second row?

Comment: I don't need the second row. Suppose I want to map with only first row (`WHERE C1 = 'v11'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on context, I would use one of bellow solutions:

```
-- Source Table
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables t WHERE t.schema_id = 1 AND t.name = N'SourceTable_83648326')
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.SourceTable_83648326
END

SELECT  *
INTO    dbo.SourceTable_83648326
FROM (VALUES 
    ('v11', 'v12', 'v13', 'v14'),
    ('v21', 'v22', 'v23', 'v24')
) SourceTable(C1, C2, C3, C4)
WHERE C1 = 'v11' -- It select required source row

-- Solution #1: dynamic query
DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''
SELECT  @Columns = @Columns + N', ' + QUOTENAME(c.name)
FROM    sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE   t.schema_id = 1 -- dbo
AND     t.name = N'SourceTable_83648326' -- Don't use ORDER BY or DISTINCT !

SET @Columns = STUFF(@Columns, 1, 2, '')

DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
SELECT  up.*
FROM (
    SELECT  *
    FROM    dbo.SourceTable_83648326
    WHERE   C1 = @p_C1 -- It select required source row
) ups -- UnPivot source
UNPIVOT( NC2_Value FOR NC1_ColumnType IN (' + @Columns + ') ) up -- UnPivot'

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStatement, N'@p_C1 VARCHAR(50)', @p_C1 = 'v11' -- Replace with propper data type and max length
```

.

```
-- Solution #2: static query
SELECT  
    b.XmlCol.value('local-name(.)', 'SYSNAME') AS NC1_ColumnType,
    b.XmlCol.value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS NC2_Value -- Replace with propper data type and max length
FROM (
    VALUES((SELECT  *
    FROM    dbo.SourceTable_83648326
    WHERE   C1 = 'v11' -- It select required source row
    FOR XML RAW, TYPE))
) a(XmlCol)
CROSS APPLY a.XmlCol.nodes(N'row/@*') b(XmlCol)
```

Comment: Following XPath returns all (`*`) attributes (`@`): `row/@*` from `row` elements.

Comment: I've followed your solution#1-dynamic query. Only problem I got - `The type of column "F13" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.` The `F13` column's datatype is `ntext`. Is there any way to resolve that?

Comment: `SELECT` clause from `SELECT  * FROM    dbo.SourceTable_83648326` should include columns with compatible data types. The simplest solution is to convert all values to the same data type (ex. [N]VARCHAR or INT): `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(_), C1) AS C1, ...`. If it's not working then you should provide the `CREATE TABLE` script for `SourceTable_...`.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `UNION ALL`:

```
select 'C1' as nc1, c1 as nc2 from tablename where c1 = 'v11'
union all
select 'C2', c2 from tablename where c1 = 'v11'
union all
select 'C3', c3 from tablename where c1 = 'v11'
union all
select 'C4', c4 from tablename where c1 = 'v11'
```

Perhaps you need to add `ORDER BY nc1` at the end.

Common table expression version:

```
witc cte as
(
    select * from tablename where c1 = 'v11'
)
select 'C1' as nc1, c1 as nc2 from cte
union all
select 'C2', c2 from cte
union all
select 'C3', c3 from cte
union all
select 'C4', c4 from cte
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to do it dynamically without knowing actually how much columns I have in the table.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE for the dynamic version:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    x.NC1, x.NC2
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ' +
(SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',(''' +COLUMN_NAME + ''', ' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ')'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Tbl'            
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')) +
') x (NC1, NC2)
WHERE
    t.C1 = ''V11''';

PRINT (@sql);
EXEC (@sql);
```

---

Another method is to use `CROSS APPLY`. This is more efficient since it only scans the table once:

```
SELECT 
    x.NC1, x.NC2
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES
    ('C1', C1),
    ('C2', C2),
    ('C3', C3),
    ('C4', C4)
) x(NC1, NC2)
WHERE
    t.C1 = 'V11'
```

Reference: [An Alternative (Better?) Method to UNPIVOT (SQL Spackle) - SQLServerCentral](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/)

Comment: I really need to learn those fancy SQL Server functions. Upvote!

Comment: Thanks. I need to do it dynamically without knowing actually how much columns I have in the table.